# How do I scale a cube to fit viewport camera bounds using python?

Tags: python, camera, transforms

I have a shortcut to add a cube to the scene. Usually the cube is way too large or too small and I have to manually scale it (sometimes the scale is so out of proportion it takes me seconds to scale how I want it).

I would like the cube's dimensions to roughly fit the current camera viewport so it's quicker to scale it down/up to where I want it to be.

This is what currently happens (cube is so large it's out of screen):
[image]

This is what I want: scale is adjusted to the viewport camera bounds
[image: What I want]

How can I change the scale of an object/cube with python, so that its dimensions are inside the viewport camera bounds?

Thanks

Comment: Check out bpy.context.area.spaces.active.region_3d.view_distance